# Find for Windows gives "Access Denied" when trying recurse into lower directories? (Windows Vista)

Tags: windows-7, gnuwin32

for instance the command:

```
find "" *
```

yields:

```
Access denied - STUFF
```

Comment: I noticed that you already have a answer because someone happened to know it, but your question was pretty bad because you did not include the relevant parts of the directory structure. [You can still do that](http://superuser.com/posts/131055/edit), of course...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the find from GNUWin32, as I assume you are from the tags, it is conflicting with the [find command](http://www.computerhope.com/findhlp.htm) already built in to Windows. If you wish to use GNU find, you'll want to rename the executable to gfind for example.

Comment: Wow!  Thanks!  I wondered why the arguments to the command looked all different and windows like!